# Convergence radius

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I know the Cauchy Hadamard equation to calculate the convergence radius of a power series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$$

Is there a way to generalize this for series of the form

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^{k*n}$$ where $k$ is some natural number
or of series of the form $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n  x^{n²}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

The series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^{2n}$ is the same as $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty b_nx^{n}$, where

$$\{b_n\}_{n=0}^\infty=\{a_1,0,a_2,0,\ldots,0,a_n,0,a_{n+1},\ldots\}$$

Comment: Shouldn't that sequence start with $a_1$ instead of 0?

Comment: so it is the k-th square root out of the ordinary convergence radius (for the first part). What about the $n²$ case?

Comment: You can also make a sequence with zeroes in the $n^2$ case

Comment: yes, but I am not so sure what this means for the equation then.

Comment: @ConanOBrien In the case $n^2$ we have $b_n=a_{\sqrt n}$ if $n$ is a square and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: so $\frac{1}{R} = \limsup{(a_n)^{\frac{1}{k \cdot n}}}$ where $k=n$ for the $n²$ case?